# How can I scrape specific data from YouTube, which the API does not provide a framework for?

Tags: excel, web-scraping, youtube-api, rpa

**1.** How can I scrape the content of the 'information panel providing publisher context' on YouTube in Python, which appears only below a video and describes the reason why the channel is verified (if it is)?

Blue box below a video (see screenshot): [Information Panel providing Publisher Context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nicgS.png)

---

The scraping happens in following context: I got sent an excel file with 40,000 YouTube channel names in respective rows and have to check, whether those are verified or not. If yes, I shall provide the reason of the verification (found in the information panel). For this, I state yes/no in the next column to the channel name and the verification reason in the second next one.

**2.** Does it make sense to use a web scraper or rather an RPA or something else for this task? And if a web scraper is the right application, which libraries / tools are able to perform these tasks?

---

So far I have been working with ChatGPT and several websites to understand how to scrape data. Hence, I set up the YouTube Data API and found ways to scrape the information, whether a channel is verified or not. I have not been able to use the YouTube API for this specific data so far.

**3.** My goal is to create an application, which includes following activities:

- Extract the data (YouTube channel names) from the excel file
- Scrapes the information, if the channel is verified or not and the 'information panel content' from YouTube
- Prints into the excel file first yes / no and second the info panel content

Comment: By *information panel provider publisher context* you mean *From an international health authority
Learn how experts define health sources in a journal of the National Academy of Medicine* (English version from your screen of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3PmVJQUCm4E))? If so, then isn't it a problem in your process that [some channels](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GNZBSZD16cY) are verified but don't have such *information panel content*?